# how solve this error:Could not get unknown property 'COMPILE_SDK' for project ':expansionpanel' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: java, android-studio, import-libraries

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.COMPILE_SDK //erroe is here

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion project.MIN_SDK
    targetSdkVersion project.TARGET_SDK
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: this error is related to     compile 'com.github.florent37:expansionpanel:1.2.0

Comment: Can you post gradle file? This error can be related to line breaks after compile directives too!